# creating a unique array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, payload

Im having trouble creating an array that contains unique subset of a larger array, please help!

> Original Array `allMembers (6)[{},{},{},{},{},{}]`

```
allMembers Payload: 0:{id:1, name: Alex} 1:{id:2, name: James} 2:{id:3, name: Bob} 3:{id:4, name: lara} 4:{id:5, name: Dan} 5:{id:6, name: Jes}
```

> Second array `uniqueMembers (3)[{},{},{}]`

```
 uniqueMembers Payload: 0:{id:1, name: Alex} 1:{id:2, name: James} 2:{id:3, name: Bob}`
```

what I'm looking for is to find the users that are in `allMembers` but not in `uniqueMembers`
so my desired new array output would be the following array `resultArray`

> `resultArray (3)[{},{},{}]`

```
resultArray Payload: 0:{id:4, name: lara} 1:{id:5, name: Dan} 2:{id:6, name: Jes}
```

> My attempt

```
 for(let m=0; m<allMembers.length;m++)
        {
            console.log('Testing include statement', uniqueMembers.includes(allMembers[m])) //output always false 
                if(uniqueMembers.includes(allMembers[m]))
                {
                    console.log('ITS ALREADY IN: ', allMembers[m])
                }else{
                    this.setState((prevState) => ({
                        resultArray: [...prevState.resultArray, allMembers[m]] 
                    }));
                    console.log('ITS NOT IN: ', allMembers[m])
                }
        }// resultArray ends up the same as allMembers :(
```

Any feedback on how I can get the desired `resultArray` values would be appreciated!

Comment: is `id` is unique for each member? or you have to compare all fields to identify if it is unique?

Comment: hi @Sphinx,  yeah id is a unique field

Answer (score 1):

Build an associative array to efficiently lookup if a member should be filtered out.

```js
lookup = {}
for (const um uniqueMembers)
   lookup[um.id] = 1;

resultArray = allMembers.filter( mem => !lookup.hasOwnProperty(mem) );
```

Two solutions posted after this one suggested using `filter` and `some`. Those solutions are O(N<sup>2</sup>). This one is should be O(N), which is way better.

Comment: Yes, especially the OP emphasized it has one large array.

Comment: @Sphinx, I like your `Set` approach (upvoted), but figured I'd leave this up as an alternative.

Comment: Sure, your solution provides another approach to create one '`set`'(upvoted), and your answer analysed the time complexity to help the OP understand the solutions better.

Answer (score 1):

If your `unique` array is very huge as well, convert `unique` array to one set first, it will save time to loop the `unique` array to check the match.

Then uses `Array.filter` to get the `not in unique` elements.

```js
let all = [{id:1, name: 'Alex'}, {id:2, name: 'James'},{id:3, name: 'Bob'},{id:4, name: 'lara'},{id:5, name: 'Dan'} ,{id:6, name: 'Jes'}]

let unique = [{id:2, name: 'James'},{id:3, name: 'Bob'}]

function getNotInUnique(src, target) {
  let uniqueSet = new Set(target.map(member => member.id))
  return src.filter(member => !uniqueSet.has(member.id))
}

console.log(getNotInUnique(all, unique))
```

Comment: Other solutions suggested using `filter` and `some`. Those solutions are O(N^2). This one should be O(N), which is way better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` along with `some`.

```js
const allMembers = [
 {id:1, name: 'Alex'},{id:2, name: 'James'},{id:3, name: 'Bob'}, {id:4, name: 'lara'}, {id:5, name: 'Dan'}, {id:6, name: 'Jes'}
];
const uniqueMembers = [
 {id:1, name: 'Alex'},{id:2, name: 'James'},{id:3, name: 'Bob'}
];
const res = allMembers.filter(m => !uniqueMembers.some(({id})=>m.id===id));
console.log(res);
```